# Is there any method to make jinja2 more readable?

Tags: jinja2

When use jinja2 to make complex config, I feel confused. Is there any method to make jinja2 more readable?

```
    { set disk_ssd_count = 0 }
{ set disk_sata_count = 0 }
  {{ inventory_hostname }}:
{% if ansible_devices | length == 0 %}
    rs: []
{% else %}
    rs:
{% for disk in ansible_devices | sort %}
{% if disk | string | is_disk %}
{% if ansible_devices[disk]['rotational'] | disk_type == 'ssd' %}
{% set disk_ssd_count = disk_ssd_count + 1 %}
      - { disk_name: {{ disk | string }}, disk_size: {{ ansible_devices[disk]['size'] }} }
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    pfd:
{% for disk in ansible_devices | sort %}
{% if disk | string | is_disk %}
{% if ansible_devices[disk]['rotational'] | disk_type == "sata" %}
      - { disk_name: {{ disk | string }}, disk_size: {{ ansible_devices[disk]['size'] }} }
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This question is simply too broad and subjective to fit into the site's format.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can look at the [macros](http://davedash.com/tutorial/jinja-macros/) side